# onclick jump's to the top of the page (need to stop this)

Tags: php, javascript, html, onclick

```
<body onload="init();">
        <center>
        <form id="selector">
            <select id="book" onchange="initChapSelector();"></select>
            <select id="chap" onchange="initPageSelector();"></select>
            <select id="page" onchange="initDisplay();"></select>
            <select id="scale" onchange="setScale(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <option value="">Original Width</option>
                <option value="100%">Page Width</option>
                <option value="50%">Half Page</option>
            </select>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('Arrow up/down: scroll\nArrow left/right: prev/next page'); return false;">Help</a>
        </form>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="moveToNextPage(); return false;"> <img id="display" style="max-width:100%" src="./js/VKmanga/spinner.gif"></a>

        </center>
 </body>
```

This is my code and on everyclick my manga viewer jumps to the top
You can see it live http://dev.animelon.com/manga/

Ive tryed `href="#"` and a few other ways nothing seems to work

Thanks

Comment: The best way to solve this is to give the links real URLs so that it also works in case JS is disabled. Or use buttons instead of links. Don't abuse links.

Comment: Hi there what do you mean mate am not the best at coding. Could you explain a little more please?

Thanks

Comment: It is not about coding, it is about semantics. An `<a>` element should either link to an element on the same page or to a new page. That is the purpose and meaning of a link. If you use a button you also won't have the problem of the page scrolling...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to firebug, your `initDisplay` function (view.js line 215), you have the line `window.scroll(0, 0);`.  This is obviously what is causing the browser to scroll to the top ;-)

Comment: :D I use it but its hard if you have no idea what your looking for hehe thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="(function(e){e.preventDefault()/*do something here */}); return false;">Link</a>
```

Comment: Ive tryed href="#" and a few other ways nothing seems to work